# android layout not matching

Tags: android, listview, layout

Hi im building an app that has a gamescore activity, but its all messy, ive tried a lot of things but no luck to leave it as in the picture there:

[image]

I got it up to here:

[image]

This is my item_layout, any help will be greatly appretiated! Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <!-- pos -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textSize="11dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dip">

            <!-- team1 -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team1"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/team_logo"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:text="Equipo 1"
                android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
                android:typeface="sans" 
                android:textSize="13dip" />

            <!-- game_team1_logo -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/game_team1_logo"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:src="@drawable/list_placeholder"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dip">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dip">

                <!-- game_score_team1 -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_score_team1"
                    android:layout_width="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="10dip"
                    android:text=" 0 "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:typeface="sans" 
                    android:textSize="17dip" />

                <!-- divider -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="10dip"
                    android:text=" - "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:typeface="sans" 
                    android:textSize="17dip" />

                <!-- game_score_team2 -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_score_team2"
                    android:layout_width="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="10dip"
                    android:text=" 0 "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:typeface="sans" 
                    android:textSize="17dip" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- game_status -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/game_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" FINALIZADO "
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:typeface="sans" 
                android:textSize="17dip" />

        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <!-- team1 -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team2"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:text="Equipo 2"
                android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
                android:typeface="sans" 
                android:textSize="13dip" />

            <!-- game_team1_logo -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/game_team2_logo"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:src="@drawable/list_placeholder"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to specify EXACTLY what you want to do and what's not working. Noone will redesign your layout for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reorganized your layout. Bellow code will give you the exact layout of your desired screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="5"
              android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <!-- pos -->
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/game_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:text="26-Junio 2014"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    >
                <!-- team1 -->
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Equipo 1"
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                <!-- game_team1_logo -->
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/game_team1_logo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/list_placeholder"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dip">

                <!-- game_score_team1 -->
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/game_score_team1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=" 0 "
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                <!-- divider -->
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=" - "
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                <!-- game_score_team2 -->
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/game_score_team2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=" 1 "
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- game_status -->
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="FINALIZADO"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    >
                <!-- team1 -->
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Halconis-FC"
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                <!-- game_team1_logo -->
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/game_team1_logo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/list_placeholder"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

you can use bellow code for your ImageView if your image are not same sized,or no within your desired size.

```
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/game_team1_logo"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/list_placeholder"/>
```

My suggestion will be to use some style for your TextView to avoid code redundancy.
Let me know if you want any example.

Comment: Solution is good! but we should not practices to give full solution :)

Comment: This really nice one solution.@Shekh Shagar

Answer (score 1):

Hope you can figure out this drawing. I edited your picture and centered the team logos and scores. If this configuration is ok, you don't need to specify dimensions.

[image]